# Using this when declaring constructors with different parameters

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

So I have this class Battery, and Enum BatteryType :

```
public enum BatteryType { LiIon, NiMH, NiCd };

public class Baterry
    {
        public string Model { set; get; }
        public int HoursIdle { set; get; }
        public int HoursTalk { set; get; }
        private BatteryType BatteryType;

        public Baterry(string model) : this(model, 0)
        {
        }

        public Baterry(string model, int hoursidle) : this(model, hoursidle, 0, null)
        {
        }

        public Baterry(string model, int hoursidle, int hourstalk, BatteryType batteryType)
        {
            this.Model = model;
            this.HoursIdle = hoursidle;
            this.HoursTalk = hourstalk;
            this.BatteryType = batteryType;

        }
    }
```

Problem is, at

```
public Baterry(string model, int hoursidle) : this(model, hoursidle, 0, null)
{
}
```

I get method gets invalid argument error. How should I fix that ?

Comment: BatteryType is enum, it can't be null

Comment: Your class is spelled incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enums are not a nullable type in C#, so you can't set `BatteryType` to `null`. Either find a default value for your enum or make your enum nullable:

```
private BatteryType? batteryType;
```

Should you want to just use `0` as your default enum value, you don't have to set anything, because `0` is the implicit default value for an enum anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`BatteryType` cannot be null - it is enum.
You can define additional item in `BatteryType`, e.g. `Undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
public Baterry(string model, int hoursidle) : this(model, hoursidle, 0, 0)
```

The default value for an Enum is 0, not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

`BatteryType` is not a reference type so you can't assign `null` to it.

You should change your constructor in this way:

```
public Battery(string model, int hoursidle, int hourstalk, BatteryType? batteryType)
{
    this.Model = model;
    this.HoursIdle = hoursidle;
    this.HoursTalk = hourstalk;
    if(batteryType.HasValue)
        this.BatteryType = batteryType.Value;

}
```

The constructor now accepts as last argument a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx) `BatteryType`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make that enum nullable (defining it as `BatteryType?`) or defining a `BatteryType.None` to use.
I prefer the second option.

Answer (score 0):

I know it isn't the direct answer to your question, but have you thought about making just a single constructor with optional arguments? You can make a constructor where the user can either fill in "modal", "modal, hoursidle", "modal, hoursidle, hourstalk" or "modal, hoursidle, hourstalk, batteryType" in a single constructor. It could make it a lot easier on you?

The line would simply be:

```
public Baterry(string model, int hoursidle = 0, int hourstalk = 0, BatteryType batterytype = 0)
{
    this.Model = model;
    this.HoursIdle = hoursidle;
    this.HoursTalk = hourstalk;
    this.BatteryType = batterytype;
}
```

What this does is fill in every parameter that you yourself don't use with the default value. It makes it a lot easier on yourself as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to OOP so that's the first time I see this. It will definitely be usefull.

Comment: @MartinDzhonov No problem, just remember that the optional parameters have to be at the end, and if you use the example provided, and you want to send "hourstalk", you have to send the values for every previous parameters as well (in this case model and hoursidle). Look up http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264739.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thanks :)
Just a little fix to your code, batteryType should be 0, not null.

Comment: @MartinDzhonov You yourself defined it as null as well, so I just copied it :) Anyway, I will change it.